# Getting my ASP.NET code to run (at least) daily

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, schedule

I wrote a web-based program in ASP.NET (VB.NET) that generates a work schedule
for our 50 employees.   Everything is working except 1 part.  I have a block
of code called RunDaily() that needs to execute 1 (or more) times per day.

With 50 employees using my code... I am hoping that on any given day at least 
1 will cause RunDaily() to execute.   During a Mon-Fri week that easily happens.  But on the weekends, only 0-5 employees might using this program.  On holidays, only about 0-2 employees might.

Is there a way to guarantee that RunDaily() will run at least once per day?
Due to the nature of this web-based program... I can't really be guaranteed
that it will always happen.

As a temporary work-around, I added a meta-refresh line that refreshes the
page every 6 hours.  So even if I (or anyone) leaves their browser open... 
and displaying the page... RunDaily() will happen.

I have even gone as far as making this web-page the HOME page for a few employees browser.  But I still can't be certain they will even open their
browser on some weekends or holidays.

Is there a better way?   Will I have to pay money to have some outside
company execute http://example.com/MyProgram.aspx for me each day?  (Is there
such a company?)

Comment: you can create windows service

Comment: How would I "create a windows service"?  I can't guarantee my computer is running 24 hours a day 7/365.

Comment: not necessarily "your" computer. put the task or service on the web server...

Comment: Is your schedule stored in a database? You could create a stored procedure and a job to build it every day. It's a bad idea to run a page as a 'background job'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, that your best bet would be to write a separate program (eg. Windows service or console app and schedule job), that will run once daily, on your preferred hours, and this should run your method. You can either program it to make HTTP request, or call method from your DLL.

From the top of my head, you could also try some tool that can make HTTP GET request to your aspx page, and schedule it to run once a day.

For this however you need a computer that runs every day (can you do that on your web server?).

Answer (score 0):

Create a page that you will invoke with the Windows Scheduler - set interval to 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a .bat file with the URL to point to the said web page and have Task Scheduler run it once every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quartz.Net for the same.

```
 using Quartz;
 using Quartz.Impl;
 using System;

 namespace ScheduledTaskExample.ScheduledTasks
 {
     public class JobScheduler
     {
            public static void Start()
            {
                IScheduler scheduler =  
                      StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
                scheduler.Start();

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
              )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

See the reference link from the same.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not explained, I am making this assumption: You do not have control over the web server where this web is running and so it is out of question to install a windows service or add a task schedule on that machine and you also mentioned that you don't want to host such a service / schedule locally on your box so...

If this is true, your only option might be to host this task schedule somewhere else... Azure Web Job comes to mind.  You can definitely schedule the web job to run at certain schedule and you can just use [curl.exe](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) or something like that to hit that endpoint in your website.

To learn about WebJob head [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/).